# Is there a way to remove/hide the Add Component button in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In mono script :

```
public void ClearObjects()
    {
        GameObject[] instantiatedObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Instantiated Object");
        foreach(GameObject go in instantiatedObjects)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(go);
        }
    }
```

In editor script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomInspector : Editor
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(GenerateObjects))]
    public class LevelScriptEditor : Editor
    {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            DrawDefaultInspector();

            GenerateObjects myTarget = (GenerateObjects)target;

            if (GUILayout.Button("Clear Objects"))
            {
                myTarget.ClearObjects();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to keep components so i'm using DrawDefaultInspector() but i don't want the Add Component button at the bottom :

[image: Custom Editor]

The Add Component button is a bit annoying.

Comment: Are you able to build a custom version of the InspectorWindow, and remove the element yourself? Otherwise, you can build a fully custom https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-EditorWindows.html

Comment: @ErikOverflow the link is to create editor window i know how to make editor window but then how i replace it with the default inspector panel window ? or position the editor window on the inspector of the specific object ?

Comment: You can inherit from the InspectorWindow, which is an inspector implementation of the EditorWindow.

Comment: The easiest solution is to push the add component button down out of the window using space.  I added this line in the bottom of the OnInspectorGUI method GUILayout.Space(1000);